# PHP Graphql create fragment

Tags: php, graphql

I have this query.

```
query{
    paintInputsUser{
        username,country, views, rol
    }
}
```

however i need a way to convert those values into a unique field, searching in google i found that the best approach is by using fragment. i want this:

```
query{
    ...paintInputsUser
}
```

but i couldn't find how to create the fragment and how to add it to the schema.

This is my paintInputsUser Type

```
<?php

namespace App\GraphQL\Type;
use App\GraphQL\Support\Type;
use GraphQL;
use DB;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\ObjectType;
use App\Model\Win\Users;

class PaintInputUser extends ObjectType
{

    public function __construct(){
        $config = [
            'name' => 'PaintInputUser',
            'description' => 'Help to know which fields the creation and edition of user are available, and the respective data',
            'fields' => function() {
                return [
                    'username' => [
                        'type' => Type::nonNull(Type::string()),
                    ],
                    'country' => [
                        'type' => Type::listOf(Type::string()),
                        'resolve' => function($person) {
                            $countries = DB::select('select c.country from win_country c inner join win_user_country uc on uc.id_country = c.id_country inner join win_users u on u.id_user = uc.id_user where u.username = ?',[$person->username]);
                            $array = array();
                            foreach($countries as $country){
                                array_push($array,$country->country);
                            }
                            return $array;
                        }
                    ],
                    'cards' => [
                        'type' => Type::listOf(Type::string()),
                        'resolve' => function($person) {
                            $cards = DB::select('select c.card from win_cards c
                            inner join win_user_card_granted ucg on ucg.id_card = c.id_card
                            inner join win_users u on u.id_user = ucg.id_user
                            where u.username = ?',[$person->username]);

                            $array = array();
                            foreach($cards as $card){
                                array_push($array,$card->card);
                            }
                            return $array;

                        }
                    ],
                    'views' => [
                        'type' => Type::listOf(Type::string()),
                        'resolve' => function($person) {
                            $views = DB::select('select vp.view_name from win_views_principal vp
                            inner join win_user_view_granted uvg on uvg.id_view = vp.id_view_principal
                            inner join win_users u on u.id_user = uvg.id_user
                            where u.username = ?',[$person->username]);

                            $array = array();
                            foreach($views as $view){
                                array_push($array,$view->view_name);
                            }
                            return $array;
                        }
                    ],
                    'rol' => [
                        'type' => Type::listOf(Type::string()),
                        'resolve' => function($person) {
                            $roles = DB::select('select r.rolename from win_roles r
                            inner join win_user_role ur on ur.id_role = r.id_role
                            inner join win_users u on u.id_user = ur.id_user
                            where u.username = ?',[$person->username]);

                            $array = array();
                            foreach($roles as $rol){
                                array_push($array,$rol->rolename);
                            }
                            return $array;
                        }
                    ],
                ];
            }
        ];
        parent::__construct($config);
    }
}
```

Please someone explain me how to implement a fragment that contains paintInputsUser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fragments are used client-side, not server-side. According to the spec:

> Fragments allow for the reuse of common repeated selections of fields, reducing duplicated text in the document... Fragments are consumed by using the spread operator (...). All fields selected by the fragment will be added to the query field selection at the same level as the fragment invocation. This happens through multiple levels of fragment spreads.

So a client request might include a query like this:

```
query {
    paintInputsUser{
        ...paintInputUserFields
    }
}

fragment paintInputUserFields on PaintInputUser {
  username
  country
  views
  rol
}
```

There's nothing special you need to do server-side to enable this behavior. All spec-compliant implementations of GraphQL support fragments out of the box.

Comment: Ooohh I get it, well that's a relieve, nice explanation, thanks :)